# Libre Office Calc - Dark Modes Aren't so Dark

Tags: libreoffice, dark-mode

How can you change the default color of the spreadsheet's grid in Libre Office Calc?

I've tried applying dark-mode themes, but all the themes I've tried still leave the grid white.

[image]

If this simply isn't an option in Libre Calc, is there another spreadsheet application that does allow this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Tools / Options..., LibreOffice / Application Colors, you can specify the document background:

[image: Screenshot of LibreOffice with a black background, and the options dialog]

The grid lines’ colour can also be chosen:

[image: Screenshot of LibreOffice with black grid lines, and the options dialog]

Comment: Thank you. I'm now trying to figure out which option controls the grid line color of a selected cell. For example, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVwYZ.png) I've select cell B3, but I don't like that the grid lines are dark black. I'd prefer a lighter color to emphasize selection.

Comment: Changing `Font color` under General in the Application Colors dialog also changes the selected cell border color to match the font color. See https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/change-selected-cell-indicator-colour-calc/53686/4.

Comment: Amazingly, the true issue here is that Automatic doesn't set the cells to the system theme. https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/automatic-system-theme-should-set-document-colour-to-theme-colours/100696?u=rokejulianlockhart